# AWSTATS 7.0 not detecting OS & Robots

Tags: awstats

It would be great if anyone could help resolve the issue I'm facing.

I've recently installed awstats7.0, but somehow the Operating Systems, Robots/Spiders are not detected.  Following is the config of my Apache & awstats

Apache:

```
LogFormat ""%{X-Forwarded-For}i" %h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b %D "%{Referer}i" "%{User-agent}i""
```

Following are the entries in Apache log (normal request, pingdom check)

```
"122.16.41.99" 192.168.1.191 - - 25/Oct/2012:13:55:40 +0000 "GET /individual/images/header-pattern-bg-img.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 2136 927528 "https://www.testing.com/individual/css/common_new.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0"
"69.59.28.19" 192.168.1.191 - - 25/Oct/2012:00:20:38 +0000 "GET /individual/healthcheck.jsp HTTP/1.0" 200 11 672 "-" "Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com)"
```

AWSTATS:

```
LogFormat="%h %other %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b %D "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i""
```

Have already tried adding "%OSFamily" section in awstats.pl, but still it's not working.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, have you had any joy with fixing it?